# Is it acceptable to answer the title of a question instead of the text of the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

So, every once in a while I'll find a question where the title is of a much larger scope than the actual question. A good example is [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10207/how-to-keep-light-switches-on-when-they-are-often-being-accidentally-turned-o?rq=1) where the title is

> "How to keep light switches “on”, when they are often being accidentally turned off?"

My initial thought is "I have an answer to this!" but for some reason or other the text of the question invalidates my answer. In this instance it was

> I assume the lights are turned off when everybody has gone home, so I can't do too "permanent" of a solution.

---

That said, occasionally I'll see someone has posted an answer that starts something like

> This doesn't exactly apply to your situation, but for future Googlers...

I'm tempted to do this to this question (and others in a similar nature). Is this an acceptable form? Or should a new question be asked (possibly creating a duplicate or related question)

Comment: I would start with a comment to make the OP aware the title doesn't match the question and if that is deliberate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. The title of the question is a very short summary of the problem, and answering based only on a summary is just plain not useful. The full body of the question is the *actual question* that you should be focusing on. If the title doesn't accurately summarize the actual question or is just plain misleading, you should be focusing on rewriting the title to make it more clear rather than posting an answer that won't be helpful. Once that's done, you're free to post your own question since the question you *want* to ask and answer won't be the same as the existing one.